# django: create object from constructor or model form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

After obtaining data from a model form based on a Model, say

```
form_data = MyModelForm(request.POST)
```

Then I can either create an instance of Model by

```
instance = Model(**form_data.cleaned_data)
```

Or by

```
instance = form_data.save()
```

I wonder which one is the preferred way in the django world

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a significant difference between the two.

`instance = Model(**form_data.cleaned_data)` doesn't save the object in the database. It only creates a local instance.

`instance = form_data.save()` adds the object to the database (it performs a commit, if so supported), and it also has the side effect of triggering validation.

If you want to do custom post-processing of the object before saving it, you pass `commit=False` to the `save()` method.

```
instance = form_data.save(commit=False)
# do some stuff with instance
instance.save()
```

Comment: so is there any case the Model(**form_data.cleaned_data) may be useful?

Comment: If you are manually creating models and not using `ModelForm`.

Comment: instance = Model(**form_data.cleaned_data) and then instance.save() also save the object in the database though, right?